# KendoUi Grid page size performance issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendoUi Grid with 20k records, When i am changing  page size 20 to 200 grid taking 40 to 50 sec to work. some times it taking min. paging is client side only.

Comment: show us what you've got so far, we need to see some code please

Answer (score 1):

For large datasets, it's better to use server paging, mainly because:

- Faster loads
- Avoid wasting memory
- Avoid unnecessary database and network loads, database just gives you the number of records of the current page

You should consider enabling server paging at datasource level, and then read pagination values on backend side before performing the query to the database.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverPaging

Answer (score 0):

good question, i am also faced this type of issue.

Please use MVVM logic instance of MVC for bind the grid,

for more please find this below link.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/mvvm